# How to redirect after submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a contact.php file in my website. When a user submits the contact form, the message is displayed by the browser at www.myurl.com/contact.php. I want the user to be redirected to the root page of myurl.com.

Here is the PHP code in the contact.php file:

```
if ($_POST) {
        if ($result)  echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';

        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';
```

What are the steps I need to achieve this?

Comment: [See the `header()` page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: This is very confusing.  The title of your question does not match the text of your question.  Further, your PHP is completely invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`header('Location: index.php');`

or add `index.php` to the action of the form you are submitting:

`<form action='index.php' method='post'></form>`

or in JavaScript, to be able to first show the message, then redirect, you can use `setTimeout`:

```
<form onsubmit="redirect()" action='' method='post'></form>

function redirect(){ setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'index.php'; }, 3000); }
```

Another way could be:

```
<form action='' method='post' id='form'></form>
function redirect(){ setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'index.php'; }, 3000); }
var el = document.getElementById('form');
el.addEventListener("submit", redirect);
```

Comment: using only header will not allow him to show the message to his users.

Comment: Ok. Check the third option I added please.

Comment: wasn't me. maybe someone else didn't liked the javascript option.

Comment: What's not to like? Maybe it should've explained what's wrong, and I would improved it.

Comment: Well, there's some problems with redirecting using a time interval. First, not all people submit a form and stay on the page, if someone submit an change browser tab, when he back to the form tab we will see the redirected page, without the message. second, not all people can read an digest an message quickly enough before the redirect.

Comment: I agree, I don't like people who simply downvote and don't explain why

Comment: Yeah, but the message would be showed immediately after the form would be submitted, and then after the timer the redirect would take place. So if the user would change tabs like you say I think that he has more than a lot time to see the message.

Comment: @leo_ap people are childish and egotistical. Which means that more often than not, they go on a revenge voting spree against anyone foolish enough to leave a comment along with their vote. That's why we don't require it, and why the majority of users won't do it.

Comment: @Clive Oh, now I understand, thank you, I never thought by that way.

Comment: @leo_ap it's a sad fact, in an ideal world we'd all be mature enough to give dispassionate opinions in people's work and have them take them on board equally dispassionately. But history shows we're just not that kind of creature

Comment: @Ionut suggestions: Header work well if you set a session variable with the message to be displayed in target page. OR echo an javascript alert along with the redirection (echo '<script>alert("success!");window.location = "index.php"</script>';) I personally prefer the first option as its more flexible and permits to display the message accordingly with the site layout and graphical design

Comment: if ($_POST) {
  if ($result)  echo '<html>
    <head>
        <title>Success</title>
    </head>

    <body>
 <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
  history.go(-1);
  }, 1000);
  alert("Thank you! We have received your message.")
  </script>
        
    </body>
</html>';

Comment: This code worked. It displays alert and wait for the user to click OK then redirect to the website.